# Is there an inverse command to open in the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

By using `open`, I can open a file via terminal.

For example:

```
$ open ~/Documents/notes.pdf
```

opens the file `notes.pdf` in the Documents folder of my home directory. It shows up as a window. Now I'm wondering:

Is there an opposite terminal command with which I can close the opened window (besides `kill <pid>`)?

Comment: Do you want to quit the application or just close the window and leave the application running?

Comment: Actually quit the application. But if you know a of closing a window: That would interest me too.

Comment: @Thinkr How do you know which application to close after running `open some.pdf`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `AppleScript` via `osascript`

```
 osascript -e 'quit app "Preview"'
```

Comment: Only works on apps that have coded for AppleScript.  (But that is almost everything from Apple and a good portion of the rest).